# White screen after installing on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 8

I got the following error while installing Drupal 8 on Ubuntu 15.04.

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: "SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'checksum' in 'field list':
>   INSERT INTO {cache_config} (cid, expire, created, tags, checksum,
>   data, serialized)

I downloaded Drupal via `drush dl drupal-8 --select` and used the beta15 branch. The web facing install screens ran perfectly. It was only after pressing either link for visiting the site or running the update script did this error occur.

How might I begin trying to fix this?

The output of `php -v` is the following.

> PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:29:28)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>   with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
>   with Xdebug v2.2.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans

MySQL version is *14.14 Distrib 5.6.25, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper*.

Comment: I think probably you have a corrupted data in the cache, try to clear it

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You table is missing a field.  There could be a bug in the install of D8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this error is recoverable if you drop the `cache_config` table because cache tables are created dynamically at run time if they do not exist when using a [database backend](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Cache!DatabaseBackend.php/function/DatabaseBackend%3A%3AensureBinExists/8).

Like [Brady](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/26916/brady) suggested there may be a bug in the Drupal installer where that table was not created correctly. To dig more into this bug, if you're interested, you would need to look at the MySQL log to see what happened and try to reproduce it.